# Gramps backup files

Tags: files

I notice a new back-up file is created every time Gramps is backed up. Is it safe to remove old back-up files and only keep the most recent one?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: I'm using Gramps 5.1.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS